# visual studio vs filezilla for publishing website

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, filezilla

My first Question:Which is better publish a web site from visual studio,or upload it by filezilla?
I didn't try any of them but someone told me when using filezilla:when I try to access my website, i get a file listing and when i try to view one of them, i just get a html text version of my pages.
but then again he said filezilla keeps the website even if it goes offline,is visual studio also the same?

And my SECOND Questin:
This is a jquery or javascript function?am I right?(which one?)
I saw it in a source code of a site,why does it look strange?I can't understand it,it has been encrypted?how can I turn it to sth which is more understandable?

```
(function (a, b) {
        function c(a) { return K.isWindow(a) ? a : a.nodeType === 9 ? a.defaultView || a.parentWindow : !1 } function d(a) { if (!cl[a]) { var b = H.body, c = K("<" + a + ">").appendTo(b), d = c.css("display"); c.remove(); if (d === "none" || d === "") { cm || (cm = H.createElement("iframe"), cm.frameBorder = cm.width = cm.height = 0), b.appendChild(cm); if (!cn || !cm.createElement) cn = (cm.contentWindow || cm.contentDocument).document, cn.write((H.compatMode === "CSS1Compat" ? "<!doctype html>" : "") + "<html><body>"), cn.close(); c = cn.createElement(a), cn.body.appendChild(c), d = K.css(c, "display"), b.removeChild(cm) } cl[a] = d } return cl[a] } function e(a, b) { var c = {}; return K.each(cr.concat.apply([], cr.slice(0, b)), function () { c[this] = a }), c } function f() { cs = b } function g() { return setTimeout(f, 0), cs = K.now() } function h() { try { return new a.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") } catch (b) { } } function i() { try { return new a.XMLHttpRequest } catch (b) { } } function j(a, c) { a.dataFilter && (c = a.dataFilter(c, a.dataType)); var d = a.dataTypes, e = {}, f, g, h = d.length, i, j = d[0], k, l, m, n, o; for (f = 1; f < h; f++) { if (f === 1) for (g in a.converters) typeof g == "string" && (e[g.toLowerCase()] = a.converters[g]); k = j, j = d[f]; if (j === "*") j = k; else if (k !== "*" && k !== j) { l = k + " " + j, m = e[l] || e["* " + j]; if (!m) { o = b; for (n in e) { i = n.split(" "); if (i[0] === k || i[0] === "*") { o = e[i[1] + " " + j]; if (o) { n = e[n], n === !0 ? m = o : o === !0 && (m = n); break } } } } !m && !o && K.error("No conversion from " + l.replace(" ", " to ")), m !== !0 && (c = m ? m(c) : o(n(c))) } } return c } ...
```

it countinues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your friend told you non-sense or you understood it that way. There's more than plain file transfer in VS deploy solution (like compilation of your source code into a dll for example), that can be fine tuned and so. Filezilla on its side is just plain ftp : you send the files you wish to a server.

You're not supposed to ask 2 questions at the same time, but still, to your second question :
this looks a lot like javascript, and it probably was minimized. This is a technique in which a parser replaces variable names by short names (letters), removes whitespaces and line feeds, etc in order to make the file smaller. Oh and JQuery is actually a javascript framework so there's no big difference between both.